# Insert Knex SQL

Tags: javascript, sql, nodejs, knex

Estoy tratando de hacer esto

```
  app.get('/insert',(req,res)=>{
  knex("users")
  .returning('id')
  .insert( [{name:"jhon",lastname:"sue"}] )
  .then(
    ()=>{

      res.send('ok?');
    });
  knex().select().from('users').then(function(data){
    //do something here
    console.log(data);
    return data;

  });
});
```

Pero, obtengo el siguiente error

> Unhandled rejection Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(`lastname`, `name`) values ('sue', 'jhon')' at line 1

Que pues obviamente pasa a la hora de hacer el query, alguien sabe a que se deba?

este es el sql que estoy mandando

```
  { method: 'insert',
  options: {},
  timeout: false,
  cancelOnTimeout: false,
  bindings: [ 'sue', 'jhon' ],
  __knexQueryUid: '86c89063-dfc3-4834-92cd-a4307a5e812a',
  sql: 'insert into  (`lastname`, `name`) values (?, ?)' }
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar toda la query que se envía al servidor SQL? puedes obtenerla tal y como se indica en https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/2378

Comment: Listo lo añadí en la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminé haciendo esto y todo listo :3

```
const qu = knex().insert({name:'Chonx',lastname:'x'}).into('users');

  qu.then((res)=>{
    console.log(res)
  });
```